# Remove JSON objects which have specific field type from JSON array field in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given a collection with documents which have an array field containing JSON objects (key-value pairs) e.g.:

```
{ ..., arr : [{key: val}, {key : NumberLong(100)}]}
```

After update, the same document should look like:

```
{ ..., arr : [{key: val}]}
```

The document in *arr* field:

> {key : NumberLong(100)}

should be removed.

Is it possible to do it with MongoDB $ operators?
 I tried to use the following code to no avail:

```
 db.coll.find({}).forEach( function(doc) {
     var objs = doc.arr;
     for(var i = objs.length; i--;){
         if (typeof(objs[i].ts) == NumberLong)
             objs.splice(i,1);
     }
     db.coll.save(doc);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking to remove data from an array like this:

```
{ 
    "field" : "aaa", 
    "list" : [  "aaa",  NumberLong(123),  "bbb",  NumberLong(456) ] 
}
```

You can do this using [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) as it takes a query expression as it's argument

```
 db.collection.update({ },{ "$pull": { "list": {"$type": 18 } } })
```

---

### Edit

Since the question has changed, it still doesn't change much in the answer though:

```
{ 
    "list" : [
        { "key" : "val" }, 
        { "key" : NumberLong(100) },
        { "key" : NumberLong(123) } 
    ] 
}
```

And with basically the same query:

```
 db.list.update({ }, { "$pull": { "list": { "key": {"$type": 18  } } } })
```

Then all the `NumberLong()` types are removed.

---

Add `{ "multi": true }` where you want this to happen over multiple documents.

So this uses [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) in order to match the "NumberLong" elements, which are 64-bit integers. The values for each "type" are on the manual page.

The [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator does not suit here as:

1. It it not a valid argument to anything that can be used to **remove** elements.
2. Even used with [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and then "setting" the value to `false`, you would only match the **first** element matched in the array. At any rate you are not removing the item and would still need to use pull.

Also, to your JavaScript method, the `typeof()` you are looking for would not return as anything other than `object` which is what it is to a JavaScript implementation. You would have to test in another way.

But don't. Using the native update methods is the **best** way.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I've made a mistake in my question. The array contains JSON objects.

Comment: @user1264304 That doesn't make any real difference to the answer. I did add your specific example to show you how.